# KDE keyboard options (like ctrl:nocaps) stop working randomly

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout

edit: turns out my keyboard was disconnect/reconnecting.  KDE is supposed to handle that, but it isn't.  reported as https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=346336

I'm using Kubuntu 15.04 (kde 5.2.2-0ubuntu1).  In System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced, I have "Caps Lock -> Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl" enabled (like any sane person that uses emacslike keybindinds in anything).

This worked fine, exactly like `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`, except that it sometimes goes back to the default layout.  I didn't log out, suspend, plug in any USB devices, or do anything that would explain this.  The settings GUI still has the box checked.  Unchecking/rechecking and clicking "apply" enables it again.

**Is this normal, or a known bug?**  Am I doing something wrong?  Should / can I tell KDE to leave my input settings the hell alone and just put `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` in my session startup somewhere?

Even after using `setxkbmap` manually, and not touching KDE's settings, the keyboard stuff still gets reset sometimes.  Repeat rate is also affected.  (The delay gets set to 2.5x longer than I like, 660ms.  So I have to `xset r rate 250 35` as well as `setxkbmap`.)

I even unset the keybind for "switch keyboard layout", but it still happens maybe once per 3 hours.  I haven't detected a pattern yet in what I'm doing.

I've always used super-lightweight window managers until now, like fluxbox, but I was starting to feel the need for more powerful alt-tabbing to manage my terminals and web browser.  It's great so far, much nicer than Unity with it's fairly-bad focus-follows-mouse.

Old cruft in /etc or my home directory is not a possibility:  I did a fresh install of Kubuntu, and moved aside all my dotfiles in my home directory before logging in to KDE for the first time.  (And then cherry-picked a few, like .bash*, .less*, but not .kde, .config, .local, or .cache).  Cruft buildup from 8 years of ubuntu dist-upgrades was really starting to pile up, and with 15.04 switching to systemd, I figured it was time to get a fresh `/etc`.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem in Kubuntu 16.04. I have used 15.04 before on other machine without problem. The switching back to default only happens after screen lock, but not always.

Comment: @JanBrezina: I don't have the problem on 15.10.  I still haven't got around to upgrading to 16.04 :/

Comment: @PeterCordes Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @wizonesolutions: As I said in the first line, part of the cause was that settings were reapplied when disconnecting / reconnecting a keyboard.  It's not a problem on my current Arch Linux desktop with KDE.